# how do I see all the bands of an .hdr file generated by ENVI.

Tags: spectral-python

I am trying to list all the bands present in my .hdr file. I have more then 100 bands and it's  a hyperspectral data.

```
img = envi.open('Dun_Hyperion_Atm_Corr.hdr','Dun_Hyperion_Atm_Corr')

view = imshow(img,(29,19,9))
```

It open the image but I want to open the image after selecting one of the band present in my .hdr file.
I am using spectral library for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read the header into a [Dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) and then access the bands:

```
import spectral.io.envi as envi
h = envi.read_envi_header('Dun_Hyperion_Atm_Corr.hdr')
print(h)
print(h['bands'])
```